# XCode fails to run AppCode project

Tags: xcode, build, compilation, project, appcode

I am writing this project using AppCode: https://github.com/AndrewShmig/ASASocialServices

It works fine in AppCode, *.app file is created, simulator is working ok, but when I open and try to run current project in Xcode all I get is "Build succeeded" message. Performed "Clean", removed all from "Derived Data" folder etc - the same message.

XCode Version 4.6 (4H127)

AppCode 2.0.2

What can be the problem? How to make XCode not just build my project but also run it?

Thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recreated my project, added again ASASocialServices header files and it worked (in XCode and in AppCode).